# How to change the activity when the progress bar ends in Android?

Tags: android

I want to change the activity after the progress bar ends. Means progress Bar thread ends. I am adding the `activity2` after the thread. But the `activity2` starts as the application runs. Why is it so?

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (progressStatus < 100) {
                    progressStatus += 1;
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity2.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("key", "......"); //Optional parameters
        startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: is any error coming ? ...........

Comment: @sushildlh No there is no error but the activity is not switching.

Comment: your code intent code should be below progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus); inside thread. in this case your activity will start even before thread is over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you start the progress bar in a new thread while the start of the intent is in another thread. The thread starting the intent does not wait for the progress bar to be finished because they are asynchronous. You could solve this by starting the intent in the runnable after the while loop is done.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a new thread which is responsible for progress bar while on main thread your new activity code is executed. You need to place start activity code within the same thread.

What you can do is :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (progressStatus <= 100) {
                progressStatus += 1;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity2.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("key", "......"); //Optional parameters
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}).start();
```